# Using latest python without installing globally

Tags: python, pip, installation, virtualenv

I've a production environment with it's own python and I don't want to have more python paths.
I already have python3 and python3.4, but I want to start using 3.8 just for test.
What i would like is having a folder with my python3.8 and it's pip.

As far as I know I can accomplish this by (bash mixed to pseudocode):

```
wget latest_python
untar - change permission 
./configure --prefix=my_path/to_python/3.8
make && make install
```

The prefix command should do the trick about "not installing it globally"
now I would export my path with a easy bash script:

```
export PS1="Python3.8 $PS1"
export PATH=my_path/to_python/3.8:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/my_path/to_python/3.8
```

So i can use this as a source

```
source .activate
```

Now I can wget get_pip.py  and run it with the new python

```
wget link/get_pip.py | python
```

Now I know I should add another path to my activation source (not sure if it's this)

```
export PATH=/my_path/to_python/3.8/bin:$PATH
```

and reload my source, and now (maybe)

```
which python --> /my_path/to_python/3.8/python3.8
which pip --> /my_path/to_python/3.8/bin/pip
```

from now on (after `source .activate`) using commands python and pip should not interfere with system pythons, is this correct?
I need a "deactivate" too, but can't figure if I have to use original path or "undo" activate paths

Is the whole procedure correct? (I've some doubts about paths)
Will this procedure allow me to create virtualenvs based on the this python installation (double activation??)?

I searched a lot but didn't find all the answers.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using virtual enviroments, it kind of does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @CumminUp07 can I create a virtual env starting from python3.4, ending with a python3.8? I don't have python3.8 on thie environment. And I don't want it globally.

Comment: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#readme

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found it all
(btw I don't really understand why all point to venv)

The procedure I posted should be like this to work properly (centos oriented)

1. install gcc openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel
2. Upgrade to latest openssl (never a bad idea, just make sure your installation is compatible with `X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_host`)
3. wget python 3.8
4. configure with (changing path to real openssl)

`LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/openssl/lib ./configure --with-openssl=/usr/local/openssl --enable-optimizations --prefix=my_path/to_python/3.8`

5. make & make altinstall
6. Python 3.8 comes with pip
7. Export path to `my_path/to_python/3.8`
8. enjoy

The Venv will work normally with double activation.

(the part about SSL is for non standard install path)